# Reason for "Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 24 '=' character expected" error when executing SQL Server call through JTDS driver?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am trying to execute the following piece of SQL on SQL Server 2012, using a Java program, connecting to the database with the JTDS driver:

```
Declare @username varbinary(128); 
SET @username=convert(varbinary(128), ?); 
SET CONTEXT_INFO @username;
```

I always get the following error:

> Invalid JDBC escape syntax at line position 24 '=' character expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you want to use only `JTDS` driver? Use the `sqljdbc4.jar` instead!

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue using [this code](http://pastebin.com/ReU2b8yf) with jTDS 1.3.1 and Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing quotations marks around `?`

```
SET @username=convert(varbinary(128), '?');
```

Comment: that may be an issue, but it is not the cause of this issue (I just tested it)

Comment: try running these 3 lines , directly in sql server via management studio  is check that they work

Comment: They do! For now I am just going to make a procedure that contains these three lines and call that instead. I think its an issue with the parsing in the jtds driver.